# Method to remove all accented characters from a string

Tags: joomla-3.9

In my model i get content of input search, i just want to clean accented characters before doing a query. In Joomla! is-there a method to clean in string the accented characters ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
....
        $lang = Factory::getLanguage();
        $lang->transliterate($value);
```

```
 * This method processes a string and replaces all accented UTF-8 characters by unaccented
 * ASCII-7 "equivalents".
```

Or check the method code to be more granular:
libraries/src/Language/Language.php

```
    public function transliterate($string)
    {
        if ($this->transliterator !== null)
        {
            return call_user_func($this->transliterator, $string);
        }

        $string = Transliterate::utf8_latin_to_ascii($string);
        $string = StringHelper::strtolower($string);

        return $string;
    }
```

So you may go with

```
$string = Joomla\CMS\Language\Transliterate::utf8_latin_to_ascii($string);
```

Comment: Thanks it does the trick